# How do I calculate from discountfactor to zerorate in Python using Quantlib

Tags: python, quantlib, discount-factor-curve

I knew rate to discountfactor

```
InterestRate.discountFactor(yearFraction)
```

I want to calculation discountfactor to zerorate